# Get rel separated by comma

Tags: jquery, rel

I have this code

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="96" id="filter-categorya" />
        <label for="filter-categorya">Category A</label>
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="97" id="filter-categoryb" />
        <label for="filter-categoryb">Category B</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<div rel="96,97">A</div>
```

and the jQuery

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
       $("div").hide();
       $("#filters :checkbox:checked").join(',').each(function() {
           $('[rel='+$(this).val()+']').show();
       });
});
```

I want to show the div if the rel of li has the value 96 or 97 and 96,97

I did this but seems not to work

http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/634/

now it's displaying http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/638 but is only displaying A and 96 or A and 97, need to display when A and B are checked to display 96 97 and A(which is 96,97 rel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use jQuery [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to translate all items into an array or object. Try this:

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
       $("div").hide();
    var output = $.map($("#filters :checkbox:checked"), function(n, i){
      return n.value;
});
       $('[rel="'+output+'"]').show();
    $.each(output,function(i,v){
        $('[rel="'+v+'"]').show();        
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/6wYzw/639/)**

Comment: It work when has the value 96,97. There's any way to display also if only 96 or 97 is checked too?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/637/ but also when select A and B to display the 96 97 and A

Comment: @ChrisChong: Above fiddle is working fine. Is there anything else you are looking for?

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/637/, when only A is check to display 96. when B 97, when both to display A 96 and 97

Comment: @ChrisChong: Above shared fiddle is working fine. You can use that code.

Comment: now it's displaying http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/638/ but is only displaying A and 96 or A and 97, need to display when A and B are checked to display 96 97 and A(which is 96,97 rel)

Comment: Do you mean when A alone is checked 96 should show and when B alone is checked 97 should show and when A and B are checked A (which is 96,97) should show??

Comment: @ChrisChong: Find updated answer. Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[rel]').hide();// if initially div should be hidden otherwise remove
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {

    if($("#filters :checkbox").eq(1).is(":checked")||$("#filters :checkbox").eq(0).is(":checked")){
        $('[rel]').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('[rel]').hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: something more like http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/638/ but is only display A and 96 or A and 97, need to display when A and B are checked to display 96 97 and A(which is 96,97 rel)